# Are chain breaker pins manufacturer specific?

Tags: maintenance, chain, frugal

I broke the second (spare) pin of my Lezyne chain breaker and now need to buy more. There are no pins from Lezyne  in the shop but there is a ParkTook breaker of the same basic design and spare pins to it. Can I use these pins with the breaker from another manufacturer or should I better buy also they breaker (and many pins in advance)?

The pins are advertised as suitable for my 12 speed chain.

Comment: As there are no pins for the breaker I have anyway, I ordered the pins from another manufacturer anyway. If they will not fit, I will buy also the compatible breaker. I will post the update for this as an answer when the pins arrive.

Comment: I had a lezyne multitool that lost its chainbreaker pin.  So I got a bolt of the right thread and turned it to length.  Worked well enough for the cost.

Answer (score 2):

**Not interchangeable**

The pins for another chainbreaker that visually look almost the same design have both slightly different length and another thread. They cannot be installed into the old chainbreaker I have. Another must be purchased.

As a conclusion, when buying a chainbreaker it makes sense to check if there are also replacement pins at least available specifically for it on the market, and maybe buy some in advance. They are 5 % from the price of the tool and only one spare was included.

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, do you work in a bike shop or something? How often are you having to break chains? I've only had to do this maybe 3 times in 8 years. Just wondering how many chain breaks you get out of a typical pin.

Comment: I have bent the first pin when splitting my first chain (lack of experience does not help) while the second pin lasted two chains and failed on the third. I tend to replace the chain together with the two smallest sprockets that last about 2500 km on my E-bike.

Comment: My  Park Tool chain breaker (CT5) is still going strong with it's original pin. Gotta be 20+ breaks and that many insertions since I use Shimano chains, which until 11s , called for replacement pins rather than joining with a quick link.  Back when 8s was transitioning to 9s I had a generic breaker whose pins mushroomed, bent then broke off. I used small square bits from a variety pack of driver tips, rounding off the hex flat portion to fit into the breaker. Held solid with epoxy.  Lots of jacking around when a higher quality tool would've done far better.